# Get USB serial number using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, hardware-id

Can anyone tell me how to get USB serial number(Hardware ID) using VB.net?

Comment: Very unclear, I assume you mean the USB device.  They don't have serial numbers, only a Vendor and Product ID.  Used by plug & play, it is always the same for the same device from the same manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

You should use WMI for this, specifically querying the [Win32_USBController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394504%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The property you want to get is **DeviceID**.'

A sample WMI call in the context of a console application might look like this:

```
Dim mos As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UsbController")

For Each mo As ManagementObject In mos.Get()
    Console.WriteLine(mo.Properties.Item("DeviceID").Value)
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

You would need to add references to `System.Management` and `System.Management.Instrumentation` to use **ManagementObjectSearcher** and **ManagementObject**.

Comment: I tried your code, but its showing error: 

Type 'managementObjectSearcher' is not defined
Type 'managementObject' is not defined

Comment: Did you add Imports System.Management to the class header?

Comment: I seriously doubt the OP wants this.  The controller properties are always the same on the same machine.

Comment: The problem is - to go deeper to get to the manufacturer's ID the OP would either need an SDK from that manufacturer or develop a lower-level library that could do that. WMI goes as far as providing the IDs outlined in the post.